# button onclick dialog table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#details" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "slide",
        duration: 500
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "slide",
        duration: 500
      }

    });
});

$(document).on('click' ,'.popup' , function() {
    $( "#details" ).dialog( "open");
});
```

I want to appear table with class details when `<button class="popup" id="$row[0]">` is clicked

This JQuery script is not working. First I throught it needed `document.ready()` but it didn't help.

Comment: You need to show your HTML.

Comment: i have <div id="details></div> and button in another file which is included

Comment: With that HTML, this should work. which means your missing something else. Build a fiddle to demonstrate your problem. As it stands this question is unanswerable as there is nothing wrong with any of the information you've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.popup').click(function () {
    $('.details').dialog('open');
    // use this instead; as you mentioned <div id="details"> in comment!
    $('#details').dialog('open');
  });
});
```

Since the button is with the class `popup` so use `.`.

And `$(document).ready(function () {` is required only when you need to load the JS in the DOM ready state.

Comment: yes i need to load js in the dom ready state because '<button class="popup" id="$row[0]">' is loaded after click to menu buttons

this code isn't working also :((

Comment: Then this code should work! You can try it out, but please make sure you use the correct selectors. And also, to include the jQuery!

Comment: i'm using another jquery functions in this file and they are working fine...

Comment: Then please make sure that you're using the correct selectors!

Comment: i was using jquery library twice...